# Find my Own Cell base on Input

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following case:

Table:

```
   A   B    C    D
---------------------
1      A    B    C
2  1
3  2
4  3
```

From the table above, I will have two inputs. Let say, Input X and Input Y. Input X, will be filled only by `alpha`. Input Y, will be filled by `numeric.` For example:

```
Input X = B
Input Y = 2
```

Then, the result should be:

```
   A   B    C    D
---------------------
1      A    B    C
2  1
3  2        p
4  3
```

Does anyone know who to do this? Thank you.

Comment: So you have made your own columns and row values, which is offset by 1 in each direction, is that correct? I.e. what you call "B2" is actually "C3", etc.? And is this a requirement for your project?

Comment: Are you working with fixed or dynamic ranges? Are you looking for formulas or VBA? If it's VBA, what have you tried up until now?

Comment: @Noceo, Yes... That is correct.

Comment: @Vegard, Formula or VBA, doesn't matter. As long as I can achieve it. Better is dynamic ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a "p" in the cell identified by your Input X and Input Y, you can have ththis formula for your A1 (in the sheet it will be cell B2) `=IF($H$1&$H$2=B$1&$A2,"p","")`.

See screenshot for illustration. Have pasted the table as values for illustration in row no 8 onwards.
[image]